# How to get a word content from an element and append it to the end of a URL of a href?

Tags: javascript, html, url

There is a function called "dictionary link" in Anki as the manual explains:

> Dictionary Links
>
> You can also use field replacement to create dictionary links.
>
> Imagine you’re studying a language and your favourite online dictionary allows you to search for text using a web URL like:
>   http://example.com/search?q=myword
>
> You could add an automatic link by doing the following in your template:
>
> `{{myword}}`
>
> ```
> <a href="http://example.com/search?q={{myword}}">check in dictionary</a>
> ```
>
> The template above would allow you to search for each note’s expression by clicking on the link while reviewing.

I am now learning HTML + CSS + Javascript from scratch, I'd like to add a similar tool in my own practice website.
I want to copy the text content *(the word that I want to check in the dictionary)* of an element, add it to the end of the url. When I click the link the corresponding dictionary page will show up.

For example:

```
<span id="search">entry</span>
```

copy "entry" and add it to the end of

```
<a id="dictionary" href="http://example.com/search?q=">link</a>
```

Since I am a complete beginner, I haven't learned jQuery or other tools yet. Is it possible to do this only by HTML and Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const search = document.getElementById("search");
const link = document.getElementById("dictionary");

link.href = `http://example.com/search?q=${search.innerText}`;
```

You have to assing new `href` property to `link` by getting `innerText` of `search` element

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use these apex:

```
<a href=`http://example.com/search?q=${myword}`>check in dictionary</a>
```

Otherwise you have to build the link by js script and then assign to a element:

```
let link = 'http://example.com/search?q=' + customParam
// Fetch the tag <a>
let hrefElement = document.getElementById('#idElement');
// Change the href param with your link
hrefElement.href = link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hackdawg/dwmoen1v/18/) and try to work around

```
function clicks(){
 var foo = document.getElementById("dictionary").id
 $("a").attr("href", "http://example.com/"+foo+"?q=")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("myLink").href = customLink` will set your link to your `a` element

```js
//get input element
var inputElement = document.getElementById('param-input');
// add event to listen every time a letter is introduced
inputElement.addEventListener("keyup", composeUrl);


function composeUrl() {
   // get value from input
   var param = inputElement.value;
   // compose url 
   var customLink = "http://example.com/search?q=" + param
   //set href 
   document.getElementById("myLink").href = customLink
   //get href
   var result = document.getElementById("myLink").href;
   //print link in a div
   document.getElementById("demoLink").innerHTML  = result.toString()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="param-input" />

<a id="myLink" />

<div id="demoLink"> url composed </div>
```